# How to IgnoreQueryFilters in DbContext in EF Core when using IOC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ioc-container, ef-core-3.1

I use EF Core and the built-in IOC in .NET Core. I add `HasQueryFilter` in `OnModelCreating`, but I want to ignore that `QueryFilter` per some request, for example if my role is admin I want to ignore it, and I want to use this ignore in one method for all request.

Where and how can I do that?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // it should be placed here, otherwise it will rewrite the following settings!
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Where(entityType => typeof(ITenant).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(entityType =>
                {
                    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                 
                    .HasQueryFilter(ConvertFilterExpression<ITenant>(e => (GetTenantId() == e.TenantId), entityType.ClrType));
                });
}

private static LambdaExpression ConvertFilterExpression<Entity>(Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> filterExpression,
                 Type entityType)
{
    var newParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
    var newBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterExpression.Parameters.Single(), newParam, filterExpression.Body);

    return Expression.Lambda(newBody, newParam);
}

private Guid GetTenantId()
{
    var tenantId = new Guid();
    var _httpContextAccessor = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

    if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null && _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Any(x => x.Type == "TenantId"))
    {
        var tenant = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
                                         .User.Claims
                                         .Where(x => x.Type == "TenantId")
                                         .FirstOrDefault().Value;

        return Guid.Parse(tenant);
    }

    return tenant;
}
```

Comment: Be careful - this call `.FirstOrDefault()` *could* return a `NULL` - and then accessing its `.Value` would cause a null reference exception. Better to use `.FirstOrDefault()?.Value` to only grab the `.Value` if a non-null result is returned from `FirstOrDefault`!

Comment: @ marc_s yes you're right, but this isn't my final code and my problem is the other things.

Comment: looks like you've not even tried googling for it, here's how you can disable the query filters for specific queries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#disabling-filters

Comment: @king King you didn't understand my problem, I know how can I use `IgnoreQueryFilters`, but I should use it base on my role in application and I want to check role and use it just in one place for example in `dbcontext` per request.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create 2 DbContexts? One with the filter and one without.

Then somewhere else in your code you can decide based on cookies or tokens or whatever to use the Admin DbContext or the Filtered DbContext

Maybe make the Filtered DbContext inherit from the Admin DbContext

Comment: This project created before, and it works now, but I want to change it a little and use it for multitenancy and also use `ignorequeryfilter` base on role.